# Why is my tkinter layout changing?

Tags: python, tkinter

I made this tkinter application, and I have a bug where the layout changes and the button at the bottom disappears.

I am unable to reproduce the bug 100%. It happens at random times.
For this reason, this SSCCE may contain more than it needs. It's still a lot less than my original app.

```
from random import random
from threading import Thread, Lock
from time import sleep
from tkinter import Tk, LEFT, RIGHT, BOTH, X, Y, Listbox, Scrollbar, VERTICAL, END
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Style, Entry


class ListManager:
    def __init__(self, ui):
        self.entry_list = []

        self.ui = ui  # to notify of list update

        self.timer = ListManager.interval + 1
        self.stop = False

    interval = 1  # between updates

    @staticmethod
    def api_request() -> dict:
        new_list = ["line"]
        while random() > .4:
            new_list.append("line")
        return {"data": new_list}

    def get_entries(self):
        r = self.api_request()

        self.entry_list = []

        for line in r["data"]:
            self.entry_list.append(line)

    def run(self):
        self.timer = ListManager.interval + 1
        while not self.stop:
            if self.timer > ListManager.interval:
                self.get_entries()

                if self.ui is None:
                    print("entries:", len(self.entry_list))
                    for entry in self.entry_list:
                        print(entry)
                else:
                    self.ui.receive(self.entry_list)
                self.timer = 0
            else:
                self.timer += 1
            sleep(1)


class UI(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.style = Style()

        self.listbox = None
        self.name_entry = None
        self.entries = []
        self.mutex = Lock()

        self.init_pack()

    def init_pack(self):
        # TODO: investigate open button disappearing (probably need to repack in receive function)
        self.master.title("list")
        self.style.theme_use("default")

        add_streamer_frame = Frame(self)
        add_button = Button(add_streamer_frame, text="Add Line")
        add_button.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.name_entry = Entry(add_streamer_frame)
        self.name_entry.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)
        add_streamer_frame.pack(fill=X)

        list_frame = Frame(self)
        self.listbox = Listbox(list_frame, height=20)
        self.listbox.configure(font=("Courier New", 12, "bold"))
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.listbox, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.listbox.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.listbox.pack(fill=BOTH, padx=5, expand=True)
        list_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        open_button = Button(self, text="Open")
        open_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

    def receive(self, entries):
        self.mutex.acquire()

        self.listbox.delete(0, END)
        self.entries = []
        for entry in entries:
            self.listbox.insert(END, entry)
            self.entries.append(entry.split(" ")[0])

        self.mutex.release()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("800x400+300+300")
    app = UI()

    tl = ListManager(app)
    thread = Thread(target=tl.run)
    thread.start()

    root.mainloop()

    tl.stop = True
    thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's what it normally looks like most of the time, and should look like:

[image: normal correct]

Here's what it looks like after the bug:

[image: bottom button disappeared]

Comment: Is your gui going un-responsive when this happens?

Comment: No. And if I resize the window, the button comes back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
self.ui.update_idletasks()
```

after:

```
sleep(1)
```

**or:**

Replace:

```
self.listbox = Listbox(list_frame, height=20)
```

with:

```
self.listbox = Listbox(list_frame)
# or self.listbox = Listbox(list_frame, height=17)
```

It must be that when too much is going on there's no time spent on updating the GUI. I couldn't reproduce the 2nd screenshot directly without lowering `sleep` argument as low as `0.001`.

The root of your problem seems to be that each time something's added into the `listbox` its height(`winfo_height` which is in *pixels*) is recalculated and resized *down* from 20 character height, to 17, for which there isn't always time for before a new insertion.

Basically, your widget does *not* necessarily has a fixed 20 character height at all times, it resizes based on its content and other widgets, unless propagation is *disabled* by calling `self.listbox.pack_propagate(False)`.

---

Add:

```
print(self.ui.listbox.winfo_height())
```

after:

```
sleep(1)
```

to see its height changing for yourself.

Comment: Are you answering this question twice? How could you answer a question more than once?

Comment: Sorry, I found it. But it seems make no sense.

Comment: @Sraw I don't think this is applicable to provide multiple answers for, it's _"Why..."_. If it was, however, _"How to ..."_  I'd not have merged my two solutions.

Comment: Um... It's a little confused for me to understand what you mean... Do you mean it is applicable to provide multiple answers for different "How to..." but not for separated "How to..." and "Why..."? I think so.

Comment: @Sraw No I meant that the question is _"Why..."_ and at the core, there is only _one_ reason (at least that I could find). There are however seemingly multiple solutions to prevent what is happening, but that is _not_ what the OP asked so I provided the only reason I think why. If the OP would've asked _"How to make my button appear at all times?"_ I would provide the solutions above in two different answers.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds make much more sense.